# Friday the 13th related tables

Tags: date-and-time

This code

```
Needs["Calendar`"];
days = {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday};
c = Count[
     Flatten[Table[
       DayOfWeek[{y, m, 13}], {y, 2000, 2399}, {m, 12}]], #] & /@ days;
TableForm[
  { days, c, PaddedForm[#, {6, 4}] & /@ (100. c/Plus @@ c), 
      ToString //@ Flatten[Position[Sort[c, Greater], #]] & /@ c}, 
        TableDirections -> {Row, Column}, 
          TableHeadings -> {{"day", "numbers of 13s", "percentage", "rank"}, 
            None}]
```

will give this table: (counts of 13ths over days of week, using 400 years data)

[image]

*(this is used as an illustration of interesting fact that 13th is more likely to be Friday than any other day of week)*

How can I obtain a table that counts Fridays over days of month (1st, 2nd, ...) also over 400 years?

Comment: Do I understand the data needs correctly - you want over the 400 year period, a tally of Fridays by the day of month they fell on (regardless of month), that you'll then tabulate?

Comment: Correct. @rasher

Comment: Isn't the first position of Friday an artefact of your choice of start and end year? If you choose `{y, 1993, 2402}` Wednesday will be first.

Comment: Paraskevidekatriaphobia... http://ubpdqn.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/paraskevidekatriaphobia/ (just for amusement)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries 400 years is chosen on purpose - that's period of Gregorian calendar, and number of days is fortunately divisible by 7, so any full 400 years weekday/monthday pattern is repeated forever. You chose 410 years, but this result doesn't mean anything, no conclusion regarding probability can be deduced. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some further observations:

```
data = Cases[DayRange[{401, 1, 1}, {2400, 12, 31}, Friday], {y_, _, 13} -> y];

x = Length /@ Split[data];

{Min@x, Max@x, N[Mean@x, 10]}
```

> {1, 3, 1.720000000}

There are EXACTLY 1.72 Fridays 13th per year over a 400 year period. This can be calculated as follows:

The Gregorian calendar follows a pattern of leap years which repeats every 400 years. There are 4800 months in 400 years, therefore with 688 from the
above tables:

```
N[12*688/4800, 10]
```

> 1.720000000

```
Count[x, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> {855, 850, 295}

Pattern of the 295 years with three Fridays 13th:

```
three = Length /@ Rest@Most@Cases[Split[x /. (1 | 2) -> 0], {___, 0, ___}];

ListPlot[three, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Bottom, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 295, 59], {2, 5, 10, 11}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

This pattern is regular with a repetition of 59 (which is the 17th prime number) years:

```
Differences@Flatten@Position[three, 11]
```

> {59, 59, 59, 59}

The next scary years are:

```
 Cases[Split@Cases[DayRange[{2014, 1, 1}, {2099, 12, 31}, Friday], {y_, _, 13}
     :>y], {y_, _, _} :> y]
```

> {2015, 2026, 2037, 2040, 2043, 2054, 2065, 2068, 2071, 2082, 2093,
>   2096, 2099}

Comment: nice..."lucky" to "unlucky" years...but which are which?...now off to count some black cats...

Answer (score 12):

```
data = Cases[DayRange[{2000, 1, 1}, {2399, 12, 31}, Friday], {y_, m_, d_} :>d] // Tally // Sort;

TableForm[data[[ ;; ;; 2]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"Day", "Number of Fri."}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(Reverse@SortBy[data, Last])[[;; 5]]
```

> ```
> {{27, 688}, {20, 688}, {13, 688}, {6, 688}, {25, 687}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, very nice and simple answer! This gives me the result that Fridays are most likely to be 6th, 13th, 20th, and 27th - again scary result!

Comment: @VividD If the 13th of the month is most likely to be a Friday, and a week lasts 7 days, then it's logical that the 6th, 20th and 27th will also most likely be a Friday.

Comment: @oska - thanks for editing in table & details - I had to hit the sack right after posting...

Comment: @rasher My pleasure, I just hope I didn't destroy it ;) I don't have _v9_ :D

Answer (score 5):

```
Sort@Tally[DayRange[{2000, 1, 1}, {2399, 12, 31}, Friday][[All, 3]]]
% == data (* from rasher's post *)
(* True *)
```

or

```
Tally[Sort[DayRange[{2000, 1, 1}, {2399, 12, 31}, Friday][[All, 3]]]]
```

or

```
Through[{First, Length}[#]] & /@ 
            Split[Sort[DayRange[{2000, 1, 1}, {2399, 12, 31}, Friday][[All, 3]]]]
```

or

```
Through[{First, Length}[#]] & /@ 
            Gather[Sort[DayRange[{2000, 1, 1}, {2399, 12, 31}, Friday][[All, 3]]]]
```

All give the same result.

And

```
Commonest[DayRange[{2000, 1, 1}, {2399, 12, 31}, Friday][[All, 3]]]
(*  {6, 13, 20, 27}  *)
```